# Regex to take command and split up Command, Arguments, and Argument Values

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, command-line-arguments

Good Afternoon,

I think I am a little over my head in this particular task. I am trying to create a regex match function to input a command, and split up the command name, parameters, and parameter values.

New-Variable -Name Something -Force
Results should be

1. New-Variable
2. -Name
3. Something
4. -Force

I have come up with this so far, but it only captures the 1st argument set.

Bonus: Is there any way to make all the matches after the command incrementally named? Say Parameter1, Value1, Parameter2, Value2, etc?

```
^(?P<Command>[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)(?: +)((-\S+)(?: |:|=)(.*){0,1})(?: +)
```

---

I had no idea the PowerShell parser even existed but this is awesome. This is the code I settled on. Thank you guys for the help!

```
#Split up the command argument, needed to pull useful information from the command.
New-Variable -force -Name SplitCommand -Value ([System.array]$Null)
$null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($Command, [ref]$SplitCommand,[ref]$Null)
$SplitCommand = $SplitCommand.where({-NOT [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.text)}).text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regex for this - use the builtin parser instead:

```
# Prepare command to parse
$command = 'New-Variable -Name Something -Force'

# Parse command invocation - Parser will return an Abstract Syntax Tree object
$parserErrors = @()
$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($command, [ref]$null, [ref]$parserErrors)

if($parserErrors){
    # error encountered while parsing script
}
else {
    # No errors, let's search the AST for the first command invocation
    $CommandInvocation = $AST.Find({ $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst] }, $false)

    # Get the string representation of each syntax element in the command invocation
    $elements = $CommandInvocation.CommandElements |ForEach-Object ToString
}
```

Which, with your input (`New-Variable -Name Something -Force`), produces the following strings:

```
PS ~> $elements
New-Variable
-Name
Something
-Force
```

---

**NOTE**: arguments tightly bound to a parameter with `:` will be interpreted as a single conjoined syntax element, eg. 'Get-Thing -Name:nameOfThing' will produce only two strings (`Get-Thing` and `-Name:nameOfThing`) - if you want them split into separate strings, take that into account before converting them to strings:

```
$elements = $CommandInvocation.CommandElements |ForEach-Object {
  if($null -ne $_.Argument){
    # tightly bound argument, output both separately
    "-$($_.ParameterName)"
    $_.Argument
  } else {
    # just the parameter name, output as-is
    $_
  }
} |ForEach-Object ToString
```

Comment: it never ceases to amaze me how much I still don't know about powershell despite using it for years and writing code in it fairly frequently. Ty.

Comment: @NickW. The rabbit hole is deep ^_^ You're welcome!

Comment: Just did some testing and I don't think the second part is needed, it seems to process ":" just fine without it.

Comment: @NickW. It's not needed if you _want_ `-param:arg` represented as a single string - but if you want param names and arguments strictly separated, it is :-)

Comment: what I mean is when I pass a `-Parameter:value` it does separate them.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536775/45375) with a streamlined solution, assuming:

- you're simply interest in an array of *strings* representing the command name and its arguments.
- that the string represents a syntactically valid command, i.e. that you needn't worry about error handling.

```
$stringToParse = 'New-Variable -Name Something -Force'

$tokens = $null # Initialize the output variable.
# Parse the string as a PowerShell command.
$null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(
  $stringToParse, 
  [ref] $tokens,  # will receive a collection of tokens
  [ref] $null     # would receive a collection of parsing errors; unused here
)

$tokenStrings = $tokens.Text -ne '' # -ne '' ignores the end-of-input token
```

`$tokenStrings` then contains an array of strings with verbatim elements

`New-Variable`, `-Name`, `Something`, `-Force`.

See also:

- PowerShell's language-parser class, [`System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser)