# Regex to split a command line into args, while preserving dashes?

Tags: regex, powershell, split

Given a command line like:

```
some\path to\an\executable.exe -foo --bar-baz abc\d e --qux -tux 123 --vux 456 --
```

I'd like to get an array that looks like this:

```
some\path to\an\executable.exe
-foo
--bar-baz abc\d e
--qux
-tux 123
--vux 456
--
```

I tried using a regex like `(?=-)` but that breaks down on `--`'d args and args with a `-` in the middle like `--foo-bar`.  I can't split on spaces because args might be paths with spaces in them.

Comment: Are you parsing command line? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536569/regex-to-take-command-and-split-up-command-arguments-and-argument-values

Comment: Will that parse the non-quoted paths with spaces correctly?  My goal here is to take commandlines being output by a process I don't control and fix the non-quoted paths.

Comment: what determines the end of an unquoted path with spaces ? does it always have an extension ? if so, you can quote it with regex and then use the method shown in the linked answer with the AST

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `(?=-)` should work, it just need `\s` before the lookahead:

```bash
$theExample = 'some\path to\an\executable.exe -foo --bar-baz abc\d e --qux -tux 123 --vux 456 --'
$theExample -split '\s(?=-)'
```

This would output exactly what you want. See https://regex101.com/r/YOeQE3/1.

I believe the [linked answer provided in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536569/regex-to-take-command-and-split-up-command-arguments-and-argument-values) gives a more robust solution to the problem, but as you have stated, the paths are not quoted and may have spaces in which case you would need to quote them yourself before using it.

This might help in that case:

```bash
$theExample = 'some\path to\an\executable.exe -foo --bar-baz abc\d e --qux -tux 123 --vux 456 --'
$theExample -replace '^(?!["''])[a-z \\.:]+(?=\s-)', '''$0'''
```

See https://regex101.com/r/Y5l5KU/2.